# Tensorflow - reshape or split tensor on pre-defined value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to define a graph operation that splits a 2D tensorflow tensor  into a 3D one based on a specific value (denoted as X here), and padded on the second and third dimension.

For example, say we have the following tensor:

```
[[1, 2, 3, X, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 2, X, 5, 6, X, 8],
 [1, 2, 5, X, 8, 9, P]]
```

- X being the to split on (it could be equal to 0 or anything else).
- P is the symbol for padding.

The goal is to have the following:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [P, P, P]],
[[[1, 2, P], [5, 6, P], [8, P, P]],
[[[1, 2, 5], [8, 9, P], [P, P, P]]
```

Tensorflow provides a [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) function, but it does not solve this problem.
The [reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) function is not the solution either as the split needs to based on a specific value.

Thank you.

Comment: The goal is indeed to run this in the graph.

Comment: Is the shape of the 3D tensor fixed and known during graph creation?

Comment: The 2D size is known. The 3D shape is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) to do the split operation.